# Xamarin.Forms how open default email client on device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms if you want to open the device's default browser by tapping a Label with a link, it's simple as this:

```
private void WebUrl_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var label = sender as Label;

  string url = "http://" + label.Text;

  Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
}
```

Is there a similarly simple way to open the device's default email client with an open NewMessage with email address?

```
private void EmailClient_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var label = sender as Label;

  // what goes here?
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: For up-to-date docs, see [Xamarin.Essentials: Email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android). On .NET 6, this becomes `.NET MAUI Essentials`, which should be useable even if not using MAUI for UI, by adding `<UsingMauiEssentials>true</UsingMauiEssentials>` to your app.config.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with:

```
var address = "your.address@gmail.com";
Device.OpenUri(new Uri($"mailto:{address}"));
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Android Emulator says: 'Unsupported action - That action is not currently supported.'

Comment: Check you have configured the mail client in the emulator and also try in a real device.

Comment: It certainly does. Thanx.

Comment: @nicael have no idea how/why this happened but I can tell you it's was not me. I see no reason of doing something like that when the whole goal of SO is helping.

Comment: Ok, sorry then for disturbing you!

Comment: @nicael no worries (y)

Answer (score 4):

I actually use a Dependency Service so that I have more control over what I can send to mail client.

First I created an interface to be used by the dependency service called IEmailService.

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void CreateEmail(List<string> emailAddresses, List<string> ccs, string subject, string body, string htmlBody);
}
```

My Dependency Service for Android looks like this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(EmailService))]
namespace Droid.Services
{
    public class EmailService : IEmailService
    {
         public void CreateEmail(List<string> emailAddresses, List<string> ccs, string subject, string body, string htmlBody)
        {
            var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);

            if (emailAddresses?.Count > 0)
            {
                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail, emailAddresses.ToArray());
            }

            if (ccs?.Count > 0)
            {
                email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraCc, ccs.ToArray());
            }

            email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, subject);

            email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText, body);

            email.PutExtra (Android.Content.Intent.ExtraHtmlText, htmlBody);



            email.SetType ("message/rfc822");

            MainActivity.SharedInstance.StartActivity(email);

        }
    }
}
```

For iOS:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(EmailService))]
namespace iOS.Services
{
    public class EmailService : NSObject, IEmailService, IMFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
    {


        public void CreateEmail(List<string> emailAddresses, List<string> ccs, string subject, string body, string htmlBody)
        {
            var vc = new MFMailComposeViewController();
            vc.MailComposeDelegate = this;

            if(emailAddresses?.Count > 0)
            {
                vc.SetToRecipients(emailAddresses.ToArray());
            }

            if(ccs?.Count > 0)
            {
                vc.SetCcRecipients(ccs.ToArray());
            }

            vc.SetSubject(subject);
            vc.SetMessageBody(htmlBody, true);
            vc.Finished += (sender, e) =>
            {
                vc.DismissModalViewController(true);
            };



           UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].
               RootViewController.PresentViewController(vc, true, null);

        }


    }
}
```

Then I can just call this in my code:

```
DependencyService.Get<IEmailService>().CreateEmail(recipients, ccs, subject, body, bodyHtml);
```

This will open the mail client on each platform with the to, subject and body fields optionally poplulated.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This may work, but it's too high-level stuff for my current level of skill. I decided to accept a simpler answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This was excellent starter code for an Email Dependency Service.

Comment: Hello @Jacob Joz I know this is an old post but I'm trying to implement this solution and I got error on android on the line: "MainActivity.SharedInstance.StartActivity(email);" what is the shared instance? what do I miss? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `Launcher.OpenAsync(uri)` exists in `Xamarin.Essentials`. OpenUri is obsolete as of `version 4.3.0.` `uri = $"mailto:{address}?subject={emailSubject}&body={body content}";`

Answer (score 1):

Device.Uri is now depreciated - use this instead.

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri($"mailto:{supportEmailSetting.Value}"));

For both IOS and Android

Comment: TryOpenAsync better