# Xamarin Forms - How to make it so that a user that clicks on a email link will open the email app in the device

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, mobile

I want to make it so that when I click an (E-mail Link) and (Phone Number) in Xamarin Forms,
to launch the (Email App) and (Phone App) on the users device.

Xaml

```
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
       Style="{StaticResource DescriptionLabelStyle}">
       <Label.FormattedText>
             <FormattedString>
                   <Span Text="{x:Static resources:Lang.AccessibilityRepDesc}" />
                         <Span Text="goteborg@goteborg.se" 
                               TextColor="{DynamicResource HyperLink}">
                                    <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding EmailCommand}" />
                                        </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Span>

                                    <Span Text="{helpers:Translate OrCall}" />

                                    <Span Text="031-3650000" 
                                          TextColor="{DynamicResource HyperLink}">
                                        <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PhoneCommand}"/>
                                        </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </Span>
                                </FormattedString>
                            </Label.FormattedText>
                        </Label>
```

Code Behind

```
private void EmailClicked(object obj)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Sending Email");
}

private void PhoneClicked(object obj)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Making a phonecall");
}
```

Comment: Check Xamarin.Essentials, [email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) and [phone call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/phone-dialer?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms how open default email client on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942291/xamarin-forms-how-open-default-email-client-on-device)

Comment: With the link you sent me I was able to fix the Email button.
I'm still trying to find a fix for Phone button

Comment: when I use  this code according to docs `PhoneDialer.Open(phoneNumber);` - I get the error message `Exception while opening dialer: Specified method is not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by fallowing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57369411/xamarin-forms-make-phone-call-without-going-to-dialer-in-android)

Was really easy to fix with (Xam.Plugins.Messaging) on Nuget.
I have tested on Android, I have yet to test on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You're maybe looking for something like Xamarin Essentials. It has a lot of good API's. There is an E-mail API, you can read about it [in these Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?tabs=android)